# Lookup field as Controlling field

Tags: field-dependencies

I am creating a dependent picklist for one of my project requirement, where Controlling field is Lookup field and dependent field is picklist field. But while select Controlling field, I am not able to see my field(that field actually a Lookup field)

Can't we select Lookup field as Controlling field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only use checkboxes and picklists as controlling fields. Some special standard fields are not available as controlling fields.